# TraitError: The 'faces' trait of a PlainGeometry instance must be a list, but a value of class 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook

I have this codes in jupyter notebook on pythreejs in chrome:

the github address: https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/blob/master/examples/Examples.ipynb

the source said :Indexed Geometries

The PlainGeometry lets you specify vertices and faces for a surface.

```
from pythreejs import *
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

vertices = np.asarray([
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1]
], dtype='float32')

faces = np.asarray([
        [0, 1, 3],
        [0, 2, 3],
        [0, 2, 4],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [0, 1, 4],
        [1, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 6],
        [3, 6, 7],
        [1, 3, 5],
        [3, 5, 7],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [5, 6, 7]
    ])

vertexcolors = np.asarray([(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)])
facecolors = [[vertexcolors[i] for i in f] for f in faces]
cubeGeometry = PlainGeometry(vertices=vertices, faces=faces, faceColors = facecolors)

myobjectCube = Mesh(geometry=cubeGeometry, material = LambertMaterial(vertexColors = 'VertexColors'))
cCube = PerspectiveCamera(position=[3, 3, 3], fov=20,
                      children=[DirectionalLight(color='#ffffff', position=[-3, 5, 1], intensity=0.5)])
sceneCube = Scene(children=[myobjectCube, AmbientLight(color='#dddddd')])

rendererCube = Renderer(camera=cCube, background='black', background_opacity=1,
                        scene = sceneCube, controls=[OrbitControls(controlling=cCube)])

display(rendererCube)
```

but when running I got this error:

```
TraitError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-753dd6c3579b> in <module>()
     31 vertexcolors = np.asarray([(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)])
     32 facecolors = [[vertexcolors[i] for i in f] for f in faces]
---> 33 cubeGeometry = PlainGeometry(vertices=vertices, faces=faces, faceColors = facecolors)
     34 
     35 myobjectCube = Mesh(geometry=cubeGeometry, material = LambertMaterial(vertexColors = 'VertexColors'))

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\widget.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    198         """Public constructor"""
    199         self._model_id = kwargs.pop('model_id', None)
--> 200         super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    201 
    202         Widget._call_widget_constructed(self)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     71 
     72         # load kwarg traits, other than config
---> 73         super(Configurable, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     74 
     75         # load config

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    995             for key, value in kwargs.items():
    996                 if self.has_trait(key):
--> 997                     setattr(self, key, value)
    998                 else:
    999                     # passthrough args that don't set traits to super

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in __set__(self, obj, value)
    583             raise TraitError('The "%s" trait is read-only.' % self.name)
    584         else:
--> 585             self.set(obj, value)
    586 
    587     def _validate(self, obj, value):

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in set(self, obj, value)
    557 
    558     def set(self, obj, value):
--> 559         new_value = self._validate(obj, value)
    560         try:
    561             old_value = obj._trait_values[self.name]

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in _validate(self, obj, value)
    589             return value
    590         if hasattr(self, 'validate'):
--> 591             value = self.validate(obj, value)
    592         if obj._cross_validation_lock is False:
    593             value = self._cross_validate(obj, value)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in validate(self, obj, value)
   2322 
   2323     def validate(self, obj, value):
-> 2324         value = super(List, self).validate(obj, value)
   2325         value = self.validate_elements(obj, value)
   2326         return value

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in validate(self, obj, value)
   2236         if isinstance(value, self._cast_types):
   2237             value = self.klass(value)
-> 2238         value = super(Container, self).validate(obj, value)
   2239         if value is None:
   2240             return value

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in validate(self, obj, value)
   1675             return value
   1676         else:
-> 1677             self.error(obj, value)
   1678 
   1679     def info(self):

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in error(self, obj, value)
   1522                 % (self.name, self.info(), msg)
   1523 
-> 1524         raise TraitError(e)
   1525 
   1526 

TraitError: The 'faces' trait of a PlainGeometry instance must be a list, but a value of class 'numpy.ndarray' (i.e. array([[0, 1, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [0, 1, 4],
       [1, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 6],
       [3, 6, 7],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [3, 5, 7],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])) was specified.
```

so what should I do? best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have likely downloaded the latest revision of the example from github, but you've currently installed an earlier version of pythreejs from pypi. It seems the change to use numpy arrays for parameters is quite recent.

I'd suggest using an older version of the examples from github - this should work.

https://github.com/jovyan/pythreejs/blob/fec50b7035608279594b17c55f2bcda26229b3c0/examples/Examples.ipynb

Alternatively, download the latest version of pythreejs from git and install it by hand.